# Are there hybrid trailers which can be used for both kids and cargo?

Tags: trailer, children, cargo

I'm looking into buying a bike trailer.

Are there any bike trailers which can be used for both kids and cargo?

I think such a trailer should have:

- an even and reasonably robust floor
- removable seats
- reasonable load limits (I've seen ones with 45kg limit and ones with 60kg limit and would go with 60kg, then)
- It should be accessible from both the front and the back

I would prefer not to remove the outer fabric for using it for cargo.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid that as a recommendation/shopping question this is likely going to be closed.  The problem with questions like this is that brands and models are transitory, so while it might be possible to answer for right now, the answer might not be any use next year.

Comment: @DavidW thanks! I should have seen this coming, because it is pointed out in bold [in the help section](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Too bad because I actually found one in the meantime. One could argue that I'm not really asking for "what is the best XY", but I accept that this would not convince most people.

Comment: Well, I could also rephrase the question to something like "How can I use a kids trailer for cargo" or so, would that help @DavidW?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a sticky wicket.  On the one hand we'd love to be able to help everyone.  On the other hand, having future visitors arrive and find dozens of questions pointing them to products that they don't have access to or no longer exist would be a problem too.

Comment: You might have something with your suggestion.  Perhaps something along the lines of "what do I need to do to safely also use my kids trailer for cargo?"  You'd probably need to specify a particular kids trailer that you supposedly have, but the answers would point out if it has particular weaknesses, and frequently you'll also get pointers on how to evaluate it yourself.  If that turns out not to be the one you choose, the answers will help you when you look at other ones.

Comment: You're always welcome to ask for product recommendations in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that any kids trailer can carry cargo, but not necessarily the opposite.

I have a kids trailer, which has a cloth footwell area hanging lower than the seat area, and a cloth backrest that hooks over part of the frame.

To carry cargo, I just put it in the same space and lash it down with some light rope or a ratchet strap.  If the cargo is awkward, I have a large piece of customwood/plywood that fits in the bottom to act as a floor.

The backrest simply lays flat, and the foot rest area is good for carrying rope and spare 20" tubes for the trailer.

My trailer is rated at a maximum of 55 lbs of "live load", but I have carried 100 kg (two 4WD wheels, and separately two computer UPS) and that was successful though probably too much.

Don't carry kids and large cargo at the same time.

Comment: If OP wants walls, pop a large plastic bin in that is the right size, and strap it down with bungee cords, ratchets, or a suitably-sized cargo net.  Some even have lids for water-resistance.